# Use case for methods defined in constructor

Tags: javascript

One could write a `greet` method for instances of a `Person` object in at least two ways:

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name
  this.greet = () => {
    console.log(`hello, my name is ${this.name}`)
  }
}

// or
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name
}

Person.prototype.greet = function() {
  console.log(`hello, my name is ${this.name}`)
}
```

It's common best practice to extend an objects prototype rather than define methods within the constructor.

Is there ever a use case for defining instance methods in a constructor function?

Comment: Yes, when these methods need some "private" variable that is only available in the constructor. #[tag:closures]

Comment: The huge difference is that your constructor-created `greet` is an arrow function that closes over the `this` instance.

Comment: like.. meta programming?

Comment: to be fair, i need to give this duplicate question a heavy read, context gets twisted up for me when i read into it